Identical cubes in a sphere
Suppose that you have a sphere of radius 10cm. At most how many cubes of side 1cm can you fit in the sphere such that:

A cube can touch another cube (share a face, an edge or a point) but cannot overlap with another cube
All cubes can be rotated if necessary


This is probably a very difficult question to answer.

Even Gauss' circle problem is unsolved.  It is the same question in 2D with the squares required to be perfectly packed.  When arbitrary orientations are allowed packing problems become very hard.

Can you define clearly what you mean by your second constraint?

@BenjaminWang they don't have to be orthogonal? Such as in some of these 2D packing examples.

Update
I have improved the previous offering by taking several steps:

Working with asymmetric slices of the sphere, as can be seen in the differing radius of the top and bottom slices.

Working with asymmetric column distribution within each slice.


Those two form the biggest source of improvement, but I also considered:

The solutions for small circles posted by Erich Friedman, using a lookup table. They are better in some small slices, but do not figure here.

Finding solutions for slices in a way similar to Daniel Mathias in the 2D version of the question, and two slices of this solution use that idea (with the same colouring scheme).


I found the Mathias-type solutions by working inwards from different sizes of quadrant filling. I also tried a 3D version of the same, by working inwards from different sizes of octant, but this 10 radius sphere is hampered by a lack of any points on a half-unit grid that touch the edge of the sphere – unlike the 10 radius circle which has points at (6, 8) and (8, 6) to work with.
There might be a tighter solution with other size spheres such as radius 7 which has perms of (2, 3, 6) to work with that exactly touch the surface.
Anyway, my improved solution with 19 slices has 3496 blocks.


Unoptimized solutions, as in the earlier puzzle Identical squares in a circle. I have used either 18 or 19 slices of a sphere, and filled them as independent circles. Some of those are better filled with an odd number of columns, others with an even number.
Of course the largest of each set is less than 10.0 radius, so the optimisation found by Daniel Mathias won't fit.
On the other hand, the smallest circle with 22 blocks has a better solution with 24 blocks shown by Erich Friedman with its radius 3.110 (actually 3.122 here).
So there certainly are better solutions to be found, still using such slices. But there may be even better ones if a similar approach as Daniel Mathias is made with cuboids, departing from this slices approach.


My solution can be manipulated to fit within a radius of 9.9715, making it usable in this 3D version of the problem.

@DanielMathias instead of my slice 10. There may be other improvements if cubes are not orthogonally placed.

@DanielMathias I would need an algorithmic way to figure out rotated cubes, since I consider 1024 slice positions, each of which has 1024 column alignments, so around 20 million potential arrangements to examine.
